# Why am I getting a 403 from my localhost server, but a 200 from my postman?

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-status-code-403

So I'm trying to connect to the Bol Retailer API in order to make other requests to the API.
Currently I'm using an express node.js server to send a request to the API and to receive a token. I'm getting a 403 back from my localhost, which tells me that the request is valid but the API is denying access to the resource for some reason.

My code is written with React and I'm using the axios library for http requests.
Below is the code snippet of my current version which results in a 403 error.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();


app.get('/getBolData', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        
        const clientId = <clientId>;
        const clientSecret = <clientSecret>;
        const credentials = btoa(clientId + ":" + clientSecret);


        const response = await axios.post('https://api.bol.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials', {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials
            },
        });

        res.json(response.data.acces_token);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.log('response', error.response.data);
            console.log('response', error.response.status);
            console.log('response', error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.log('request', error.request);
        } else {
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        res.status(500).send('Server error occured');
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The 403 error logs the following:

```
{ title: 'Unauthorized request', status: 403 }
Object [AxiosHeaders] {
  date: 'Thu, 21 Dec 2023 11:42:26 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/problem+json',
  'content-length': '45',
  server: 'undefined',
  'x-envoy-decorator-operation': 'ingress-controller-eng-pro-bol-com-api.eng.svc.cluster.local:80/*',
  via: '1.1 google',
  'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000'
}
```

I've been stuck on this for almost 2 days now, the customer service is not helpful in the slightest bit. I've tried to do the request in Postman and to my surprise, it does work if I generate a token with OAuth2.0 and use that to send other requests.

[Postman OAuth2.0 parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9sGV.png)

I've tried the following things to deal with the 403 but none of them worked:

- Delete cache and cookies
- Tried a proxy to fetch the requests
- Double checked my credentials and the required headers
- Enabled CORS and changed my implementation to the current server version to prevent further problems

Does anyone have any tips to help me with this problem?

UPDATE:

So I've managed to find a piece of code that works. But how is it different than my initial approach?

```js
        const clientId = <clientId>;
        const clientSecret = <clientSecret>;
        const credentials = btoa(clientId + ":" + clientSecret);

        let config = {
          method: 'post',
          url: 'https://login.bol.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials',
          headers: { 
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials, 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
        };
        
        axios.request(config)
        .then((response) => {
            res.json(response.data.access_token);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: Weird that it is working in postman, according to the bol.com documentation (https://api.bol.com/retailer/public/Retailer-API/authentication.html#_step_2_acquiring_an_access_token) the URL should be `https://login.bol.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials` does this make any difference to you?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes, I've used this URL but that results in a 401 with 'Bad client credentials' and that can't be the problem as I've checked the credentials numerous amount of times...

Comment: could you try and remove the `Access-Control-Alow-Methods` headers? In the documentation I also read `Please note that at this time the authentication service only supports Accept: application/json, so providing different values may lead to unexpected errors.`

Comment: Tried that as well, did not work unfortunately. Still the same error message. I think it might be a problem with the grant_type. I have to send it with the URL but in postman I'm sending it with the headers. Don't know how to fix it though

Comment: Found a working solution. Read update

Comment: the solution is exactly implementing the two things I've pointed out. 1) use the correct URL and 2) remove the `Access-Control-Alow-Methods`. That is how it is different from your initial approach